# Javascript Hoisting concept

Tags: javascript, hoisting

What is the difference between below two codes in terms of Hoisting.

```js
function hoist1() { 
    console.log("Hello1 ",message);
    message='Hoisting is all the rage!'
}

hoist1(); 

function hoist2() {
  console.log("World ",message);
  var message='Hoisting is all the rage!'
}

hoist2();
```

Comment: They are both undefined because hoisting has no effect on assignment, it only applies to not throwing an error because the variable has been declared.

Answer (score 1):

case 1:

```
function hoist() {
  console.log(message);//undefined
  var message='Hoisting is all the rage!'
}

hoist();
```

equals to:

```
function hoist() {
  var message;//undefined
  console.log(message);
  message='Hoisting is all the rage!'
}

hoist();
```

so,you got undefined;

And var hoisting happens **before the code execute**

case2:

```
function hoist() { 
    console.log(message);//error,because message is not defined.
    message='Hoisting is all the rage!'
}

hoist();
```

If you remove the console,**after code executed**,it is like

```
var message;
function hoist() { 
    //console.log(message);
    message='Hoisting is all the rage!'
}

hoist(); 

console.log(message);//Hoisting is all the rage!
```

so ,you can visited the `message` out of the `hoist`.

`message` here is **assigned without declaration** will be a **global variable**.

And it happens **when code is running and meets a assignment without declaration.**

Comment: Hey Xian, main motive was not to intervene global variable into it , so Based on the above query , iam getting output as error on first case and undefined on 2nd case . So both time it wont print undefined

Comment: @PiyushBiswal, what is your problem?in your  2nd case,you should get undefined of message.

Comment: @PiyushBiswal,Did you mean that you didn't get undefined of message in your 2nd case?i got undefined.Actually,i was confused of your last words 'So both time it wont print undefined'

Comment: @xianshenghu , for 1st case it will throw error but in 2nd case it will provide undefined . 
because of this behaviour , i got confused with hoisting concept .

Comment: suggest you read book 'JavaScript The Definitive Guide 6rd Edition'，page53

Answer (score 0):

This question contains both hoisting and scope.

Hoisting means that functions and variables get defined in the top of the current scope, at line 1 for your functions.

When a variable is defined without the `var` keyword, JavaScript looks in the current and the parent scopes (outside the function) to see if it has been defined. If using strict mode, it would fail after it finds that it’s not defined. If not strict mode, it will be defined as a global variable. Use strict mode! This is usually an unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The result should be:

```
undefined

undefined
```

Hoisting will move the declarations to the top and so the second function will became the executed one, or `hoist`. However the `var` does not allow for hoisting of the value, just the variable, as `var x = 5` for example will declare x at top but set X afterwards. As a result, the evaluation of message is `undefined`.

Comment: Based on the above query , iam getting output as error on first case and undefined on 2nd case . So both time it wont print undefined.

Comment: Are you running the entire code block as a script or are you plugging it into an interpreter? If you put in each call separately to a console interpreter then the outcome will be different, but running the code block as stated in OP&#39;s question by itself results in two `undefined`s.

Answer (score -1):

In the first example:

> ```
>  message='Hoisting is all the rage!'
> ```

will modify (or create if it doesn't exist) the `message` property of the global `window` object.

In the second example you're just setting an otherwise unused local.

Comment: first example will result in error, it will not create window property

Comment: @pwolaq No. There is *no* error and it *will* create a property on `window`.

Comment: are you sure? because I have check that and it results in `Uncaught ReferenceError: message is not defined`

Comment: @pwolaq Yes, tested in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. On what environment do you get an error? Did you use the *exact* code from the question?

Comment: @str I have tested it in Chrome console. I suspect that it may force `strict` environment because it works otherwise as your suggested. My bad :(

Comment: Using the function as shown in the question will result in an undefined variable error (just checked – by putting the code in a `<script>` block. However you'll notice I don't address that aspect in this answer because my reading of the question was about declarations rather than current values (or lack of them).